# CAD Workflow, Add Update Imported model option to the FBX,OBJ etc. and keep materials

Tags: .fbx, obj

Is there a way to update the CAD geometry after it has been changed but keep all the Blender materials? I want to avoid having to re-apply materials every time that there are changes on the design.

There are lots of topics but still no progress or any solution.

[Link obj files into blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119957/link-obj-files-into-blender)

[Link obj files into blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119957/link-obj-files-into-blender/190261#190261)

[How can Blender automatically update a 3d model from a changing network file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56584/how-can-blender-automatically-update-a-3d-model-from-a-changing-network-file)

https://blenderartists.org/t/add-update-imported-model-option-to-the-fbx-dea-sketchup-importers/1186256

[Re-import updated CAD model into blender, retain existing surface materials and settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163372/re-import-updated-cad-model-into-blender-retain-existing-surface-materials-and)

https://blenderartists.org/t/cad-workflow/1266661